# Mysql query for getting restaurant remaining seats

Tags: mysql

I have problem to write mysql select query in which I can get number of free seat in time slot.

Let me define my problem user mysql query:

Suppose I have one table `restaurant_booking`.

[image]

If there are total **25** seats in restaurant and one user want to **15** seat between 2:00pm - 4:00pm how to check in booking table till this time how many seats are available?

If i see this booking table there are **20** seats already booked till this time slot, then how should i get only 5 seats are available?

If anyone have any idea, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: This is hard to accomplish with this data structure, because you're storing the start and end booking times as strings. It would be easier if you stored the times and dates in one column as a DATETIME or a TIMESTAMP type.

Comment: Jesbus, Thanks for comment. Suppose i have changed these start & end booking table structure as datetime then again problem in front of me how to check booked seat before booking in restaurant.

Comment: No dear HerrSeker!, it is not my homework. It is problem which i am facing to book a table in restaurant in my online hotel/restaurant booking project. I think you can understand as you are older member on stackoverflow. I have heard that this site have great developer in each technology..

Comment: When I make a reservation at a restaurant, they ask me when I want to arrive, never when I want to depart.

Answer (score 1):

The logic looks like:

```
SELECT (25-SUM(booked_seat)) FROM rest_booking 
WHERE end_booking_time>2 
AND
start_booking_time<4
--2 & 4 are the new customer's start&end booking time
```

But I agree with @Jesbus, dates should be stored as Timestamps.

Comment: The condition is not enough. It will include bookings that start after the desired timeframe

Comment: @RonenYacobi: I think, i am not getting your point. Could you please give an example where this condition does not fit?

Comment: Look at booking_id=4 - your query will also sum this row, even though it is not inside the timeframe

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select
    sum(booked_seat) as seatsAva
from
    restaurant_booking
where 
    STR_TO_DATE(end_booking_time,'%r') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%r')
```

and after that you can minus `seatsAva` from `25`, above `query` will give you the result of currently `unavailable` seats count

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (granted your columns are dates or unix time stamp):

```
SELECT (25-SUM(booked_seat)) AS free_seats 
FROM restaurant_booking 
WHERE 
(end_booking_time>start_time_of_desired_booking AND end_booking_time<=end_time_of_desired_booking)
OR 
(start_booking_time>=start_time_of_desired_booking AND 
start_booking_time<end_time_of_desired_booking)
```

replace start_time_of_desired_booking and end_time_of_desired_booking with your values
Let me know if it works for you